# Mouse dies and stops responding

Tags: mouse

My mouse randomly dies. It works fine for minutes, sometimes hours after login but then just stops working.

The issue has persisted over more than one mouse and more than one iteration of Ubuntu. I'm currently using a wierd, Logitech USB mouse and Ubuntu 14.04 It *might* be a hardware problem in the actual computer, but I find that unlikely.

lsusb lists the mouse both before and after it dies, as does xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer

Unplugging and plugging in again does not work.

One solution I found here on askubuntu was to use xinput to disable and then enable the mouse. This works as intended while the mouse is still working, I can turn it off and on again. When the mouse has died, I tabbed into the terminal to try it again. Running xinput --disable [mouse id] freezes both the keyboard and power button (!) ...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: How long have you had the mouse? You could have a broken wire.

Comment: The mouse is a couple of years, but as I said the problem has appeared on an entirely different mouse, too

Answer (score 2):

I've narrowed it down to a hardware problem. Tried with a much more basic mouse, and so far it works.

The mice I've tried before have both been fairly complex gaming mouses, with speed features and extra buttons. I suspect this has something to do with it, since I've run across other mentioning this as a source of problems. I am, however, far from sure.